# How would one parse XML in Kotlin with encoding utf8?

Tags: android, class, utf-8, kotlin, xml-parsing

I am new to Kotlin, trying to build my first Android App.
I have an xml string that I would like to parse to a class. The xml comes from a soap webservice call and the result is in a string called xmlOut.pcReturnData which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><ShipmentDetail><Waybill><WaybillNumber>0087073606</WaybillNumber><ServiceType>ECONOMY ROAD</ServiceType><CurrentStatus>Proof of delivery</CurrentStatus><CurrentStatusCode>POD</CurrentStatusCode><DeliveredDate>18052017</DeliveredDate><DeliveredTime>1200</DeliveredTime><ReceiverName>PIET</ReceiverName><NumberOfPieces>3</NumberOfPieces><TotalWeight>         330.00</TotalWeight><Contents/><ManifestReference/><OriginSuburb>MILNERTON</OriginSuburb><OriginHub>ATL</OriginHub><DestinationSuburb>BLOEMFONTEIN</DestinationSuburb><DestinationHub>BFN</DestinationHub><ShipperReference>0087073606</ShipperReference><TrackingEvents><BranchCode>ATL</BranchCode><EventDate>15052017</EventDate><EventTime>1158</EventTime><EventDescription>Waybill Created</EventDescription><EventCode>WBLCRE</EventCode></TrackingEvents><TrackingEvents><BranchCode>ATL</BranchCode><EventDate>15052017</EventDate><EventTime>1224</EventTime><EventDescription>In Trip</EventDescription><EventCode>WBLALL</EventCode></TrackingEvents><TrackingEvents><BranchCode>CPT</BranchCode><EventDate>15052017</EventDate><EventTime>1530</EventTime><EventDescription>On Floor</EventDescription><EventCode>WBLDAL</EventCode></TrackingEvents><TrackingEvents><BranchCode>CPT</BranchCode><EventDate>15052017</EventDate><EventTime>2238</EventTime><EventDescription>In Trip</EventDescription><EventCode>WBLALL</EventCode></TrackingEvents><TrackingEvents><BranchCode>BFN</BranchCode><EventDate>16052017</EventDate><EventTime>1534</EventTime><EventDescription>On Floor</EventDescription><EventCode>WBLDAL</EventCode></TrackingEvents><TrackingEvents><BranchCode>BFN</BranchCode><EventDate>16052017</EventDate><EventTime>1858</EventTime><EventDescription>In Trip</EventDescription><EventCode>WBLALD</EventCode></TrackingEvents><TrackingEvents><BranchCode>BFN</BranchCode><EventDate>17052017</EventDate><EventTime>1722</EventTime><EventDescription>Comments captured</EventDescription><EventCode>WBLCOM</EventCode></TrackingEvents><TrackingEvents><BranchCode>BFN</BranchCode><EventDate>17052017</EventDate><EventTime>1726</EventTime><EventDescription>In Trip</EventDescription><EventCode>WBLALD</EventCode></TrackingEvents><TrackingEvents><BranchCode>BFN</BranchCode><EventDate>18052017</EventDate><EventTime>1835</EventTime><EventDescription>Waybill Delivered</EventDescription><EventCode>WBLDLV</EventCode></TrackingEvents><TrackingEvents><BranchCode>CHLR</BranchCode><EventDate>19052017</EventDate><EventTime>1047</EventTime><EventDescription>POD</EventDescription><EventCode>PODCRE</EventCode></TrackingEvents></Waybill></ShipmentDetail>
```

The class i created:

```
data class ShipmentDetail(val Waybill: Waybill?)

data class TrackingEventsList(val EventDate: Number?, val EventTime: Number?, val EventDescription: String?, val BranchCode: String?, val EventCode: String?)

data class Waybill(val TrackingEvents: List<TrackingEventsList>?, val WaybillNumber: String?, val CurrentStatus: String?, val ShipperReference: String?, val CurrentStatusCode: String?, val ManifestReference: String?, val NumberOfPieces: Number?, val DeliveredDate: Number?, val OriginSuburb: String?, val TotalWeight: Number?, val Contents: String?, val DestinationSuburb: String?, val ServiceType: String?, val DestinationHub: String?, val DeliveredTime: Number?, val ReceiverName: String?, val OriginHub: String?)
```

I would like to parse from the xml to the class ShipmentDetail, is there a build in XMLParser in Kotlin or would I need to use some kind of plugin or extension?

Comment: [Introduction to JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) ... With JAXB you can annotate your classes and then just un/marshall the xml as needed. There are also other solutions available, but JAXB is probably the most well known (as it is also part of the Java SE; don't know up to which version however ;-)).

Comment: hmm... the introduction seems way too much to read and the most important seems to be hidden... you may want to lookup another source if it looks too complicated to you... basically it is as simple as: `@XmlRootElement data class ShipmentDetail(@XmlElement val Waybill : WayBill?) { /* no-arg constructors however are required! */ constructor() : this(null) }` and `val obj  = JAXBContext.newInstance(ShipmentDetail::class.java).createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(yourXmlSource)` with an xml similar to `<ShipmentDetail><Waybill/></ShipmentDetail>`. You may assign parts of it to variables though.

Comment: @Roland thanks, your answer's pointed me towards the Jackson Library, will try that